# How to merge list of dicts

Tags: python

How to merge a list of dictionaries in Python? I have 2 sets of data:

```
a = [{'date':'1/1/2019'},{'date':'1/1/2020'},{'date':'1/1/2021'}]
b = [{'value':'2'},{'value':'5'},{'value':'6'}]
```

How can I merge it to the below result?

```
[{'date':'1/1/2019','value':'2'},
 {'date':'1/1/2020','value':'5'},
 {'date':'1/1/2021','value':'6'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that both are `list`s of `dict`s of the same length, you can do:

```
c = [{**item[0], **item[1]} for item in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Way cool! Can you explain this?  I'm having trouble understanding how this works. - Oh..maybe I see...`**_d` does just like what it would in a function call...k1=v1, k2=v2, etc...and that works to define a dict when put in curlies, and you can even put multiple `**` in the same curlies.  Is that about it?

Comment: Yes, this is dict comprehension similar to wherever `**kwargs` shows up.

Comment: There is no need to use enumerate and fetch elements from `a` directly while fetching those from `b` with an index. Use `zip()` instead. Also, I don't know why you put a `_` in `_d`'s name, it seems random and done just to make it harder for beginners to read and understand.

Comment: theberzi - true, thanks. `zip` is probably cleaner. I put the underscore because `_d` was a variable in the loop only, not to be confused with the `a`s out there.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3.9, The union operator is added to `dict`, so this works:

```py
>>> a = [{'date':'1/1/2019'},{'date':'1/1/2020'},{'date':'1/1/2021'}]
>>> b = [{'value':'2'},{'value':'5'},{'value':'6'}]
>>> [x|y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
[{'date': '1/1/2019', 'value': '2'}, {'date': '1/1/2020', 'value': '5'}, {'date': '1/1/2021', 'value': '6'}]
```

See [PEP 584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/) for details.

Answer (score 6):

```py
c = [{**a1, **b1} for a1,b1 in zip(a,b)]
```

Here I have used list comprehension, **a1 and **b1 are used for unpacking and mapping the key-value pair of both list of dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

`[{**i[0],**i[1]} for i in zip(a,b)]`

Comment: oops, i think i have arrived late to the party :)

Comment: No prob.  I like yours a bit better.  It's more symetrical.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex: `i` is a tuple of the dicts from a and b, you can just do `[{**k,**j} for k, j in zip(a,b)]` and avoid having to index into the lists, which is faster and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods for doing that.
One is :

```py
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i].update(b[i])
    
print(a)
```

if you have python 3.9 and above

```py
new_list = [a[i]|b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

for checking your python version:

```py
import sys
print (sys.version)
```